# How to hide the link to an external web page in a HIT before workers accept the HIT

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, mechanicalturk

On Amazon Mechanical Turk, I include a link in a HIT to an external web page where workers are going to do the actual HIT. However, I want to hide the link from the workers until they accept the HIT.

Can this be done by adding some JavaScript on the page while creating the HIT? Or this has to be done through MTurk API or libraries such as `Boto`

Comment: What do you mean by "hide"? If you mean just don't display it in the rendered web page, then Chris's answer will work. But if you mean you don't want the URL to show up even in the HTML source code you're going to have to add something on the server side.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Amazon will pass variables in the url query string when opening your external web page. For this use case, you want to look at `assignmentId`. If `assignmentId` is `ASSIGNMENT_ID_NOT_AVAILABLE` the worker is previewing the HIT. (More info in the [mturk docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMturkAPI/ApiReference_ExternalQuestionArticle.html#ApiReference_ExternalQuestionArticle-the-external-form-preview-mode).)

You can grab those variables with the following javascript:

```
var assignmentId = $.getUrlVar('assignmentId');
var workerId = $.getUrlVar('workerId');
var hitId = $.getUrlVar('hitId');
if (assignmentId == "ASSIGNMENT_ID_NOT_AVAILABLE"){
  // Worker is previewing the HIT
}
else {
  // Worker has accepted the HIT
}
```

where `$getUrlVar` is a simple jquery plugin:

```
$.extend({
  getUrlVars: function(){
    // From http://code.google.com/p/js-uri/source/browse/trunk/lib/URI.js
    var parser = /^(?:([^:\/?\#]+):)?(?:\/\/([^\/?\#]*))?([^?\#]*)(?:\?([^\#]*))?(?:\#(.*))?/;
    var result = window.location.href.match(parser);
    var scheme    = result[1] || null;
    var authority = result[2] || null;
    var path      = result[3] || null;
    var query     = result[4] || null;
    var fragment  = result[5] || null;

    if (query === null || query === undefined) {
      return {};
    }
    var vars = [], hash;
    var hashes = query.split('&');
    for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
    {
      hash = hashes[i].split('=');
      vars.push(hash[0]);
      vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
    }
    return vars;
  },
  getUrlVar: function(name){
    return $.getUrlVars()[name];
  }
});
```

Comment: great solution. idk why they wouldn't have an api call that lets you know when a worker has accepted the hit but this is a slick work around. Do you know if there is an api call to see what hits are being worked? THANKS!